# Cease Image Display on User Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, removechild

I'm attempting to interface with the qualtrics.com JS API and having trouble because the code below will not stop displaying the image at the end of its animation loop. Qualtrics is a survey hosting site and I basically need all the images displayed on the animation loop coded for below to vanish as soon as a survey respondent clicks the next button. The addOnLoad() function is part of the qualtrics API, and it's working (as the alert part of the function works), but I think there's something wrong with the remove(imageLinks[i]); option that I'm trying, as the images persist in being displayed. Any suggestions?

```
var imageLinks = ["http://i.imgur.com/iUjHm4e.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/89Bh81C.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/qKecE0F.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/s5LzrE1.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/thRmkE8.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/mjfqeKv.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/w9EpXNq.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/b2rP5RQ.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/NDLm5QQ.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/7nohNKf.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/4Qtz8KB.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/xTwSsBe.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/KwXNQjR.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/5BVvvci.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/bU0jnnD.jpg",
    "http://i.imgur.com/YKy6K6u.jpg",

];

function display(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    //img.style.position = "absolute";
    //img.style.left = "270px";
    //img.style.top = "300px";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    return img;
}



function remove(img) {
    document.body.removeChild(img);
}



i = 0;

function animation_loop() {
    var im = display(imageLinks[i]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        i++;
        if (i < imageLinks.length) {
            animation_loop();
        remove(im);}
    }, 150);
};

animation_loop();

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if(element.type == "radio") {
            alert("Good job choosing an answer!");
            remove(imageLinks[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cbjrobertson/o0onrxa1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to clear the timeout on the click event; this will prevent the inner function from firing again, breaking the loop.

As for the removal function, you need to pass in the DOM element again, like you did with the loop. So something like this:

```
var loopTimeout;
var im;

function animation_loop() {
    im = display(imageLinks[i]);
    loopTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        i++;
        if (i < imageLinks.length) {
            remove(im);
            animation_loop();
        }
    }, 150);
};

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if(element.type == "radio") {
            clearTimeout(loopTimeout);
            alert("Good job choosing an answer!");
            remove(im);
        }
    }
});
```